# Data with space required, Strip function issue

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, request, strip

I need help on having space (as given in HTML source code) between data extracted from table no. 6 using Python like  **195640 421 ******* in my extracting output. Currently I am having output without any separator or spaces. Anyhelp would be appreciated:

URL is given [here](http://ec.europa.eu/environment/ets/ohaDetails.do?returnURL=&languageCode=en&accountID=&registryCode=&buttonAction=all&action=&account.registryCode=&accountType=&identifierInReg=&accountHolder=&primaryAuthRep=&installationIdentifier=&installationName=&accountStatus=&permitIdentifier=&complianceStatus=&mainActivityType=-1&searchType=oha&backList=%3C%C2%A0Back&resultList.currentPageNumber=1589&selectedPeriods=)

The formatted Code is given below, need help with the output data having spacing between digits as given on the webpage and html source code. I think that it is caused by using strip function and thereby I am not having spaces between the scrapped output:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "http://ec.europa.eu/environment/ets/ohaDetails.do?returnURL=&languageCode=en&accountID=&registryCode=&buttonAction=all&action=&account.registryCode=&accountType=&identifierInReg=&accountHolder=&primaryAuthRep=&installationIdentifier=&installationName=&accountStatus=&permitIdentifier=&complianceStatus=&mainActivityType=-1&searchType=oha&backList=%3C%C2%A0Back&resultList.currentPageNumber=1589&selectedPeriods="

    r = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text,"lxml")
    for items in soup.find(id="tblInstallationContacts").find_next_sibling().find_all("tr")[:-5]:
        data = [item.get_text(strip=True) for item in items.find_all("td")]
        print(data)
```

Comment: do you want `print("\t".join(data))`?

Comment: Please give expected output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `str.split` with `str.join`

**Ex:**

```
for items in soup.find(id="tblInstallationContacts").find_next_sibling().find_all("tr")[:-5]:
    data = [' '.join(item.text.split()) for item in items.find_all("td")]
    print(data)
```

**Output:**

```
[u'Compliance Information']
[u'EU ETS Phase', u'Year', u'Allowances in Allocation', u'Verified Emissions', u'Units Surrendered', u'Cumulative Surrendered Units**', u'Cumulative Verified Emissions***', u'Compliance Code', u'Options']
[u'2005-2007', u'2005', '', '', '', u'0', u'0', u'A', u'History', u'Details on Surrendered Units']
[u'2005-2007', u'2006', '', '', '', u'0', u'0', u'A', u'History']
[u'2005-2007', u'2007', '', '', '', u'0', u'0', u'A', u'History']
[u'2008-2012', u'2008', u'272063', u'219592', u'219592', u'219592', u'219592', u'A', u'History', u'Details on Surrendered Units']
[u'2008-2012', u'2009', u'272063', u'188608', u'188608', u'408200', u'408200', u'A', u'History']
[u'2008-2012', u'2010', u'272063', u'246152', u'246152', u'654352', u'654352', u'A', u'History']
[u'2008-2012', u'2011', u'272063', u'214697', u'214697', u'869049', u'869049', u'A', u'History']
[u'2008-2012', u'2012', u'272063', u'219409', u'219409', u'1088458', u'1088458', u'A', u'History']
[u'2013-2020', u'2013', u'199349', u'235869', u'235869', u'235869', u'235869', u'A', u'History', u'Details on Surrendered Units']
[u'2013-2020', u'2014', u'195640 421 *****', u'244203', u'244203', u'480072', u'480072', u'A', u'History']
[u'2013-2020', u'2015', u'191900 416 *****', u'248367', u'248367', u'728439', u'728439', u'A', u'History']
[u'2013-2020', u'2016', u'188132 364 *****', u'279441', u'279441', u'1007880', u'1007880', u'A', u'History']
[u'2013-2020', u'2017', u'184336 314 *****', u'259952', u'259952', u'1267832', u'1267832', u'A', u'History']
[u'2013-2020', u'2018', u'180513 265 *****', '', '', '', '', '', u'History']
[u'2013-2020', u'2019', u'176655 218 *****', '', '', '', '', '', u'History']
[u'2013-2020', u'2020', u'172794 174 *****', '', '', '', '', '', u'History']
[u'* Verified Emissions entered/updated after deadline of EU ETS Phase Year']
```

Comment: Thanks Rakesh, its working now. If possible then can you take a look at the another issue that I posted for help related to data scrapping from table with duplicate (same Header titles) ? Will be much appreciated. -  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50647481/data-scrapping-from-website-having-multiple-tables